# Svelte: Trigger update of {#each} in child component

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte

I am trying to update a child component with an `{#each}` loop inside it to add additional items by `push()`ing them to the array that is iterated by the child component. While an individual variable (say a string or number) works fine and array that feeds a `{#each}` loop doesn't seem to.

I am using a `bind:` to pass live data to the child component and have also tried to use a `$: array` statement in the child. Whatever I do, pushing new data to the array in the parent has no effect on the child, is there a way to do this or do I have to split off and re-render the whole child component `{#each}` loop every time?

I have posted my test script in a REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/e1f24f8fccfa4533a1d682d163af9a66?version=3.49.0

Type text in to the input box and hit the 'Note This' button.

If you watch the JS Console you can see the array expanding, but the `{#each}` loop is not rendering the extra items to the child component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Svelte works in a way where it only detects updates from assignment. You can read more about it here:
https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-2-assignments-are-reactive.
Using methods such as push won't automatically trigger updates.

In your case you can just add `testData = testData` after pushing the new object and it works fine.

Comment: I added a revised REPL into the answer that illustrates @GRaykovski 's answer in the context of the code